# How to resolve couldn't get connection factory client error on android

Tags: android

couldn't get connection factory client running the MapsDemo sample application on emulator. I'm getting the error: couldn't get connection factory client.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: I would be very interested as well, can't get any tiles displayed, I believe my Map Key isn't the problem. Thanks for any input !

Answer (score 0):

I had reinstalled Android dev kit on my new system and the debug.keystore had changed.
Once I used the keytool to make a new MD5 and registered that with Google I was back in action with a fresh apiKey.

"Couldn't get connection factory client" is a weird message for an invalid apiKey !